# What happens to downvoted questions?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I was wondering what happens to the **downvoted questions** on Stack Overflow?

Whether they get removed from website on daily/monthly/yearly basis? Or are there some other clean up criteria?

Comment: Ooops, wrong one, but the answer is in the first link bringing [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba)